# Clarification about a MIPS program that asks to Provide whether a month has 28/29, 30 or 31 days

Tags: assembly, x86, mips, mars-simulator

Due the lack of sources I could get my hands on, it seemed strange to me that nobody posted a program as a solution for this question on the internet in MIPS (unless I'm that bad at surfing the internet). I require clarificatoin about whether my program can be written in a more efficient and optimized way rather than just spamming Labels&Branches!!

```
.data
    msg : .asciiz "Give the month: "
    msg1 : .asciiz "This month contains 31 Days."
    msg2 : .asciiz "This month contains 30 Days."
    msg3 : .asciiz "This month contains 28/29 Days."
.text
.globl main
main:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg
    syscall
    
    li $v0,5
    syscall
    move $t0,$v0   #t0 contains given month
    
    li $t7,7
    li $t2,2       
    li $t1,0
    
    div $t0,$t2
    mfhi $t3
    mflo $t4
    
    bgt $t0,$t7,etiq3
    beq $t0,$t2,etiq2
    beqz  $t3,etiq1
    bgtz $t3,etiq
    
    
    etiq:
    li $v0,1
    addi $a0,$s1,0
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg1
    syscall
    j exit 
    
    etiq1:
    li $v0,1
    addi $a0,$s0,0
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg2
    syscall
    j exit
    
    etiq2:
    li $v0,1
    addi $a0,$s0,0
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg3
    syscall
    j exit
    
    etiq3:
    beqz $t3,etiq
    bgtz $t3,etiq1
    
    exit:
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: Consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `bgtz $t3,etiq` is pointless, execution falls through to that label anyway if the previous `beqz` is not taken.  Using `div` to divide by 2 is very inefficient vs. a shift.  You could `andi` with `1` to get the remainder mod-2, and right-shift to get the quotient.  You're making the same syscall each time, the only thing differing is the string pointer, so unless you want to do tail-duplication optimization (so your paths of execution don't converge again after branching), you should put the common instructions in a common block.

Comment: Generally speaking, problems like this where there's no simple pattern for the output is best solved with a lookup table. Something like `.word 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31` would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't well commented so hard to follow. Especially why you are printing `$s0` and `$s1` neither of which seem to be initialized.

As for an optimized solution, a possibility would be to use a bitmap (2 bits per month):

```
.data
    msg : .asciiz "Give the month: "
    msg1 : .asciiz "This month contains 31 Days."
    msg2 : .asciiz "This month contains 30 Days."
    msg3 : .asciiz "This month contains 28/29 Days."
    table: .word msg3, msg2, msg1
.text
.globl main
main:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg
    syscall

    li $v0,5
    syscall

    # 00 = 28/29, 01 = 30, 10 = 31
    li $a0, 0x099a6620  # 1001 1001 1010 0110 0110 0010 0000
    sll $v0, $v0, 1     # 2 bits per month
    srlv $a0, $a0, $v0  # shift the bitmap
    andi $a0, $a0, 0x0c # keep the 2 bits
    lw $a0, table($a0)
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

You could of course just put the message pointers into a table with 12 entries as well for somewhat simpler code at the expense of more memory.